# How do I know if Newton's method converges to the right zero?

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I want to find a real number $\lambda$ such that $\lambda^n-pw \lambda^{n-1}- p w^{-1} \lambda -1 + 2p = 0$, where $w = e^{2 \pi i/n}$ and $0<p<1$. In order to do that we define a polynomial (which has $\lambda$ has a zero) $$q(x) = x^n-pw x^{n-1}- p w^{-1} x -1 + 2p $$
We will use Newton's method:
$$x_{i+1}=x_i - \frac{q(x_i)}{q'(x_i)}$$
starting with $x_0 =1$.
After some computations, (for sufficiently large $n$)
$$|x_{i+1}-x_{i}| = \left( \frac{p}{(1-p)}\frac{4 \pi^2}{n^2} \right)^{2^i} \frac{1}{n + O(1)}$$
and
$$|x_{i+1}-x_0|=O(1/n^3)$$
which allows us to conclude that for sufficiently large $n$, the sequence $x_0,x_1,...$ converges to a limit point $z$, which by continuity of $q$, must be a zero of $q$.
Then, you can also check that
$$x_1=1 - \frac{p}{(1-p)}\frac{4 \pi^2}{n^3 }+O(1/n^5)$$
and
$$|z-x_1| = O(1/n^5)$$
which means that
$$z=1 - \frac{p}{(1-p)}\frac{4 \pi^2}{n^3 }+O(1/n^5).$$

And they say that this limit must be $\lambda$, which is the part that I don't understand. Couldn't the sequence converge to another zero of $q$ which is not $\lambda$?

Comment: It's $$x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{q(x_i)}{q'(x_i)}$$

Comment: thanks, edited now

Comment: How do you determine what the "right" zero $λ$ is? For $0<p<\frac12$ you get exactly one positive real root, so there is no chance of converging to something else.

Comment: How can you tell that there is exactly one positive real root for $0<p<1/2$?

Comment: The full proof is here (Lemma3) https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0210469.pdf

I don't think you need there is nothing in the rest of the pdf needed to understand this part of Newton's method, I think